# laravel 4.1 routing issues

Tags: php, laravel, routes

im using laravel 4.1 with php 5.3 but the thing is that i my url it only work when i enter

```
http://localhost/happy_Road/public/index.php/register
```

i want it to be this way

```
http://localhost/happy_Road/public/register
```

because when i add a css file it not getting detected and it show me the route like this

```
http://localhost/happy_Road/public/index.php/css/bootstrap.css
```

need some help please :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the instructions for setting up "pretty URLs" at http://laravel.com/docs/installation#pretty-urls. It'll depend on which web server you're using locally - examples are given for both Apache and nginx.

Additionally, you should link to CSS files using absolute URLs - the `index.php` shouldn't affect your stylesheet routing at all. This can be done in a couple ways:

```
{{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.css') }}
```

or:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this to add your `css` files:

```
{{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.css') }}
```

Regarding, `index.php`, it requires `url rewrite` and by default in your `public` folder there is a `.htaccess` file should be available for `apache` server. Check [Pretty Urls](http://laravel.com/docs/installation#pretty-urls) section on `Laravel` website for more information.